# Why is R library not loading in app.powerbi.com?

Tags: r, powerbi, tidyr

I keep getting the following error on app.powerbi.com:

"Error in pivot_wider(data, names_from=names,values_from=values): could not find function "pivot_wider""

I load the 'tidyr' package as a required library.
I get the same error when using "spread" instead of pivot_wider.

When I specify the function using:

```
tidyr::pivot_wider(data, names_from=names, values_from=values)
```

I get a different error:
"Error in loadNamespace(name): there is no package called 'tidyr'".

PowerBI Desktop everything works perfectly fine. It's only on the published PowerBI report that I get the error.

What can I do to resolve this issue?
Alternative library / function to 'pivot_wider' or 'spread'?

Comment: If you get an error that says "there is no package..." then you need to install that package on that system. Run `install.packages("tidyr")` once on that machine to make sure the package is available.

Comment: Are you using R in the Power Query part or in the visual?

Comment: R is in the visual. It is a custom visual that I'm creating utilizing the pbiviz library. The package is installed which is what's odd. It shows up as an installed package in R. When I attempt to install again, it doesn't change anything. The visual works perfectly fine in PowerBI Desktop. It's only when I publish that I get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to verify using print statements that the report on powerbi.com was not able to access the r packages that were installed.

I was using a .libPaths()[3] to point to the location where my libraries were installed, but this didn't work in powerbi.com.

I ended up re-installing R to a location where I could install packages to, since admin rights are necessary to write to the C:/users/program files location.

Comment: You can use .libPaths and directly specify a location. That might have worked without a reinstall.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the suggestion. I tried that based on this article:
http://blog.datainspirations.com/2018/02/02/power-bi-r-home-directory-vs-library-trees/

When I specified the correct path, it worked locally on powerbi desktop but not on the report on powerbi.com.